# how to import nested JSON data into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, metro-bundler

I have a JSON file called ui-components.json that holds config data for user interface components used in a mobile app.  Here is a sample of data in the file:

```
{
  "picker": {
    "color": {
      "choices": ["brown", "black", "red", "green"],
      "defaultChoice": "red"
    },
    "size": {
      "choices": ["small", "medium", "large"],
      "defaultChoice": "medium"
    },
    "direction": {
      "choices": ["north", "south", "east", "west"],
      "defaultChoice": "west"
    }
  },
  "number": {
    "size": {
      "choices": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
      "defaultChoice": "5"
    },  
  }
}
```

Currently, this data is being imported selectively, like so -

```
import { picker } from '../../config/ui-components';
```

While this works, a lot more data is being imported than necessary (more than shown in the sample above).  The file that's importing the config data only needs `color` so I tried the variations below but the editor indicated errors and sure enough, when an attempt was made to run the app, it threw errors.

```
// variations attempted
import { picker.color } from '../../config/ui-components';
import { picker.color as color } from '../../config/ui-components';
import { picker['color'] } from '../../config/ui-components';
import { picker['color'] as color } from '../../config/ui-components';
```

Is it possible to do this?  If so, what is the correct syntax?  If not, why not?

Comment: [MDN Nested object and array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Nested_object_and_array_destructuring)

Comment: Does `ui-components` have an export statement at the bottom?

Comment: @otw it does not.  `ui-components` is a .json file.  I am under the impression that export statements are only for .js files.

Comment: @David784 How does the `import` step fit into the approach of the link you provided?  Would the entire `picker` object still need to be imported?  ...I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: You can’t import parts of a JSON file separately. You could use `fetch` instead of `import`, that way you can at least discard the unused data after filtering out the part that you need.

Comment: @Kokodoko Why will it allow importation of `picker` from the .json file but not an element nested within `picker`?  If it allowed importing the top level elements, I wonder why it won't import nested elements.

Comment: Sorry, I saw that you were working with a JSON object and my mind immediately went to destructuring assignment. The `import` syntax you're using is intended for importing named exports...I had no idea you could make it work on a file with no exports at all. Just out of curiosity, what environment are you doing this in? webpack? node? browser?

Comment: @David784 I'm working with Vue Native which is a wrapper for React Native APIs.  It uses node modules and a bundler called Metro.

Comment: Even if that did work, syntactically, it would still have to load the entire module.

Comment: @knot22 When you use `import` with a JSON file, you embed the whole JSON file into the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't import part of the json data but if the environment you use supports commonjs syntax  you can do something like this

```
let{
    picker:{
      color:colors
    }
  }=require("../../config/ui-components") //if the Json file extension is .json 

  console.log(colors)
```

Comment: If the `color` from the JSON file is to be put into a variable called `color` within the JavaScript it looks like `color: color` works and also just `color` (no semicolon or word after it).  Is the `: colors` part necessary only if the JS variable name is to be different from the JSON element name?

Comment: No the `:colors` is not necessary at all in fact you can access the variables like this `let{picker:{ color,size,...}}==require("....)` however if your object is deeply nested or complex, allocating variables will make the structure of the obj in your JS file cleaner and easy to read/ you can easily locate parts of your object that you need

Comment: Everytime I see a tip like this, the code itself is unsurprising. This is immediately readable  and obvious as to how it works, yet somehow I couldn't see it before coming here. Works in create-react-app. Great tip, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I am not aware of an environment where you can import JSON directly like that, so you might be using some tooling that is processing the files. Not sure if it would support anything like that but you can also just do this:

```js
import { picker } from '../../config/ui-components';

const pickerColor = picker.color;
```

It's unlikely you'd get any performance advantage by doing it any earlier in the import, unless your tooling supports shaking JSON which I've never heard of.